# What probability distribution is this?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, random-permutations

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or feedback.

I have a discrete 1D probability distribution represented as a vector $\textbf{p}$, $p_i = p(x_i)$.

I am interested in finding the Wasserstein (earth mover's) distance between $\textbf{p}$ and a random permutation of itself, $\textbf{p}'$. i.e.

$W = \sum_{i=0} \mid \sum_{j=0}^i p_j - \sum_{j=0}^i p_j' \mid $

My question is what is the probability distribution of $W$? Is of course positive and, from simulations, heavy near the origins. So maybe a gamma or beta distribution? It would be amazing to see a way to derive this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer heavily depends on the concrete $p$. Surely its not a gamma or beta distribution, these are distributions with density.

Comment: If $p'_1, p'_2, \dots$ is a random permutation of $p_1, p_2, \dots$, why wouldn't $W$ be zero?

Comment: By the law of large numbers $\sum_{j=0}^i p_j'$ is close ti $i/n$ with high probability. So if $\sum_{j=0}^i p_i$ is close to $i/n$ for most $i$, then this distribution is peaked near zero, and if it's far from $i/n$, then it's peaked away from zero.